# Online java compiler

Tags: java, operating-system, system, compiler-optimization, java-compiler-api

I have server which compiles java files. How Can I prevent my server from bad java files.  For instance my server shouldn't compile code which deletes all files from server.

Os: windows
Java version 1.8
C#

```
runner = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                FileName = JavaCompiler.PATH_TO_COMPILER,
                Arguments = " -cp " + pathToFile + " Main",
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WorkingDirectory = pathToFile
            }
        };


        runner.Start();
```

This code will execute java program.

My aim is prevent my programm from codes like this

```
 File f = new File("c:\\");    
 String[]entries = index.list();
    for(String s: entries){
        File currentFile = new File(index.getPath(),s);
        currentFile.delete();
     }
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem in bit details? example would be great.

Comment: Run the compiler/runtime under a user with limited permissions.

Comment: You seem terribly confused. Your command starts the Java compiler, but gives it arguments as though it was going to execute the supplied program, not compile it.  Make up your mind. If you're just offering a compilation service, the code won't be executed, so it doesn't matter what it does. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: https://www.domjudge.org/

Comment: @Arjan, Thanks for link.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this at compile time. For example, the only way to *guarantee* that a program cannot delete all files via compile-time analysis is to stop the program from deleting *any* file.  And even that is difficult ... because there are various subtle ways to delete files that could be hard to detect using static analysis.

You would be better off using a Java `SecurityManager` to enforce the restrictions at runtime.  The security manager / sandbox approach (if implemented correctly) would allow you to permit a program to read / write / delete *some* files, and not others.

Better still.  Run the JVM that runs the user's code in virtual machine, a chroot jail, or something similar implemented using (say) SELinux.  Make it so that if the user does manage to subvert your defenses, they don't do any irreversible damage.

Or even better ... don't offer a service where (effectively) anonymous people can run Java code.  (Why would you *want* to make this kind of problem for yourself?)

Comment: [Yeah](http://ideone.com/), [why](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php) [would](https://www.compilejava.net/) [*anybody*](http://www.browxy.com/) [do](https://www.codechef.com/ide) [that](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler)! [It's](http://compileonline.com/) [insane](http://www.onlinecompiler.net/java)!!  [Nobody](http://www.guru99.com/try-java-editor.html) [wants](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/) [that](https://code.hackerearth.com/), [right](https://repl.it/languages/java)! [Completely](http://codetwist.com/) [Useless](https://idedr.com/)! ;-)

Comment: @Arjan - I never said it was useless.  I said why should >>the OP<< do it.  (Especially since ... as you seem to be saying ...  there are many other people already providing a similar service!)